# Watts & ohms of resistor

Tags: resistors

I want to connect 24 led 3.2v in series with a power supply of 230v dc. Which resistor should I use. Also pls mention watts of the resistor which I can use

Comment: If you use 3 strings x 24 LEDs no resistor is needed for 230Vdc. And if using 20mA that is 4.6 Watts. But if you use only 1 string then LEDs use 1.52W and Resistor uses 3.1W at 125'C ( if 3W type) so use a >=5W  type.  Do you know Ohm's Law?

Comment: The question is incomplete. You need to tell us what type of LED you have, or the current you are operating them at.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiufrO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

24  3.2V LEDs is 76.8V, leaving about 150V

24 x 3.2 = 76.8

230 - 76.8= 153.2

Assuming you want 20mA in the LEDs

you need 7.5 Kilo ohms resistance and 3W

150 / 0.020 = 7500

150 * 0.020 = 3

a 3 watt resistor is only good for 3 watts in free air 
so you probably want a tougher resister like 5W 
the resistor will get hot so provide a way for the heat to escape.

Comment: Could you include a short description of how you got the values you gave?  **I** know how, you know how.  The person asking **doesn't** know, and will have to ask the same question the next time with 100VDC and 15 LEDs at 2.3V.

Comment: Some derating should be used. Don't use a 3 W resistor, take one rated for 5 to 10 W.

Comment: Why are we all assuming 20 mA LEDs? The white LEDs are usually 50 mA. I very much doubt OP is trying to string together 24 red LEDs to 230V.

Comment: Also, this circuit will fail instantly. The LEDs will be unable to withstand the reverse voltage during negative half-cycles.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Adafruit Circuit Playground app]

I don’t believe 3W.  The string draws 24*0.020A or 0.48A.  Roughly 110W before dropping the voltage.  I’m not sure the Adafruit calculator isn’t suffering from an internal overflow to get 8000 watts, but a 3W resistor is more likely to act like a fuse than a resistor.

Comment: See answer above: 150 * 0.020 = 3 or to make it clear 150V * 0.02A = 3W.

Answer (score 0):

The strip drops from the 230v:
24*3.2v= 76.8v

230v-76.8v = 153.2v

In the resistor will drop 153.2v

R=V/I so R= 153.2v/0.02= 7660 Ohms

Power in R, V*V/R = 153.2*153.2/7660 = 3.064W

Use a single 7.5K 5W or two 3.9K 3W each.

Total power: 230 *.02=4.6W

In the LED strip 76.8 * .02=1.536W